# Configuring embedded Tomcat to serve FIPS-compliant HTTP2 with BouncyCastle

Tags: ssl, tomcat, bouncycastle, fips

I'm trying to configure an embedded Tomcat server so that it can serve HTTP2 in FIPs mode, using BouncyCastle's FIPs libraries. I've set the accepted protocols to TLSv1.2+TLSv1.3.  I've tried various suggested cipher suites, but it seems no matter what I set as the cipher suite, Chrome/FF rejects connections on the grounds of "Inadequate Security".  If I disable HTTP2, it does not matter what I set as the cipher suite - it just works.

I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Can you provide the code used to setup Tomcat and the versions of BC, Tomcat and JRE used?

Comment: Yes - I'll send a link to a gist in a moment.  I will say I made "progress", in that now I cannot make any secured connections, with or without http2 enabled, with my current cipher suite.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dajester2013/541d5c78271f453dbab288e6c43194ee

Comment: Also, tried with Java 11, 14, and 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When BC is in FIPS mode, it requires `PKIX` as algorithm for the `KeyManagerFactory` and `TrustManagerFactory`:

```java
Security.setProperty("ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm", "PKIX");
Security.setProperty("ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm", "PKIX");
```

Without these two lines the server will be unable to retrieve the keys required by the cipher suite.

Comment: Tried setting those two in BCFIPSUtil.java, but any request now throws an exception on the server: 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x020x000x010x000x010xfc0x030x03h_~+@_cO0xa30x90,]0xec0xe40xc3v0xcc0xcd0x030x03o.Q/0xb0u0xca]. HTTP method names must be tokens

Comment: Those are caused by HTTPS requests against a HTTP connector. Is the `SSLEnabled` property set to `true`?

Comment: Yes - https://gist.github.com/dajester2013/541d5c78271f453dbab288e6c43194ee#file-tomcatserver-java-L133

Comment: Well, looking at the logs though, the protocol handler is http:

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio2-127.0.0.1-8880"]

Comment: Rookie mistake - forgot to set proper build parameters. D'oh!  Anyways, I'm still getting ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH.

One of the things I'm trying to do is, on the fly load a PEM-encoded certificate and private key into a BCFKS to use in an SSLHostConfigCertificate instance.

Comment: This, along with ensuring that the listen address is set properly (was set as /0.0.0.0, instead of just 0.0.0.0), fixed the problem. Thank you.